# How to replace tag with php code?

Tags: php

I am completely new to PHP but have this one thing on website that I have to fix.

Let's say that in html I use tag `{{user_login}}` for which I want that it always show member username. In PHP it's `<? echo $userData['username']; ?>`.

My question is what do I need to do in PHP to have username displayed on front-end when this tag is used? Hopefully I explained it correctly...

I'm using {{user_login}} as `<input value="{{user_login}}">`

Comment: Wouldn't you already have a templating system in place if you're using curly-placeholder syntax? Else, why not just edit the actual PHP code into your HTML file?

Comment: What templating system are you using? Twig?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$yourHtml = '<div>{{user_login}}</div>';
$yourHtml = str_replace('{{user_login}}', $userData['username'], $yourHtml);
```

Comment: I've tried  this but doesn't work. The {{user_login}} is being used inside <input value" ">. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the HTML, replace the `{{user_login}}` with `<?php echo $userData['username'] ?>`